# Issues with performing two seperate 'functions' when opening a file with Python

Tags: python, file

This may seem like a bit of a basic question but why am I unable to perform two separate 'functions' on a file when I open it. To clarify, in the below code I iterate through the `.json` files in a directory and for each I want to perform two seperate 'functions' (I know they aren't actually functions): 1) find out how many times "text" appears in it, and 2) get rid all list items that contain "total comments".

```
import os
import json
import re

for filename in os.listdir():
    y = 0
    if ".json" in filename:
        with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
            print(filename) 
           #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
            x = f.read()
            u = re.findall("text", x)
            print(len(u))
            y+=len(u)
           #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#            
            comments = json.load(f)
            for item in comments:
                if 'total comments' in item:
                    comments.remove(item)
            print(comments)
```

However, the first 'function' is the only one that seems to actually work; in this instance the code will result in a `JsonDecodeError`, and if the order is switched around then the `regex` 'function' won't find any results. The only explaination I can think of is that the variable `f` is changing its type when I perform `read()` or `json.load()` on it, but that almost seems counter intuitive. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I understand why calling `read()` twice wouldn't work but I am still unsure why that would apply to `json.load()`. Is it the underlying mechanism the same insomuch that the read pointer is at the end of the file?

Comment: That's what I was hinting at, so did you try seeking to the beginning before doing the `json.load()`?

Comment: I have added `seek(0)` between them and it has fixed the problem so I suppose it must be!